# How can I vectorize this for loop in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

The code is below:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array(range(15)).reshape(5,3)  # X's element value is meaningless
flag = np.random.randn(5,4)
y = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 0])  # Y's element value in range(flag.shape[1]) and Y.shape[0] equals X.shape[0]
dW = np.zeros((3, 4))  # dW.shape equals (X.shape[1], flag.shape[1])
for i in xrange(5):
    for j in xrange(4):
        if flag[i,j] > 0:
            dW[:,j] += X[i,:].T
            dW[:,y[i]] -= X[i,:].T
```

To compute dW more efficiently, how to vectorize this for loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
# has shape (x.shape[1],) + flag.shape
masked = np.where(flag > 0, X.T[...,np.newaxis], 0)

# sum over the i index
dW = masked.sum(axis=1)

# sum over the j index
np.subtract.at(dW, np.s_[:,y], masked.sum(axis=2))

# dW[:,y] -= masked.sum(axis=2) does not work here
```

See the documentation of [`ufunc.at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) for an explanation of that last comment

Comment: With repeat values in the `y` index, `-=` can have buffering problems.  That's where the `ufunc` `.at` can help.

Comment: So the first line `masked = np.where(flag > 0, X.T[...,np.newaxis], 0)` use broadcasting, brilliant! So one way to vectorization is increasing dimension?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vectorized approach based upon [`np.add.reduceat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) -

```
# --------------------- Setup output array ----------------------------------
dWOut = np.zeros((X.shape[1], flag.shape[1]))

# ------ STAGE #1 : Vectorize calculations for "dW[:,j] += X[i,:].T" --------
# Get indices where flag's transposed version has > 0
idx1 = np.argwhere(flag.T > 0)

# Row-extended version of X using idx1's col2 that corresponds to i-iterator
X_ext1 = X[idx1[:,1]]

# Get the indices at which we need to columns change
shift_idx1 = np.append(0,np.where(np.diff(idx1[:,0])>0)[0]+1)

# Use the changing indices as boundaries for add.reduceat to add 
# groups of rows from extended version of X
dWOut[:,np.unique(idx1[:,0])] += np.add.reduceat(X_ext1,shift_idx1,axis=0).T

# ------ STAGE #2 : Vectorize calculations for "dW[:,y[i]] -= X[i,:].T" -------
# Repeat same philsophy for this second stage, except we need to index into y.
# So, that would involve sorting and also the iterator involved is just "i".
idx2 = idx1[idx1[:,1].argsort()]
cols_idx1 = y[idx2[:,1]]
X_ext2 = X[idx2[:,1]]
sort_idx = (y[idx2[:,1]]).argsort()
X_ext2 = X_ext2[sort_idx]
shift_idx2 = np.append(0,np.where(np.diff(cols_idx1[sort_idx])>0)[0]+1)
dWOut[:,np.unique(cols_idx1)] -= np.add.reduceat(X_ext2,shift_idx2,axis=0).T
```

Comment: Thanks. Althougn it has lines of codes, it is easier to understand.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
ff = (flag > 0) * 1
ff = ff.reshape((5, 4, 1, 1))
XX = ff * X
[ii, jj] = np.meshgrid(np.arange(5), np.arange(4))
dW[:, jj] += XX[ii, jj, ii, :].transpose((2, 0, 1))
dW[:, y[ii]] -= XX[ii, jj, ii, :].transpose((2, 0, 1))
```

You can further merge and fold these expressions to get a one-liner but it won't add any more performance.

**Update #1: Yep, sorry this is not giving correct results, I had a typo in my check**

Comment: Since X is only ever indexed at `[x, y, x, z]`, can it not be made 3 dimensional?

Comment: I think your first three lines are better spelt `XX = np.where(flag[...,np.newaxis,np.newaxis], X, 0)`